# Apache using 99% CPU, seems to be doing something to images?

Tags: linux, apache, magento, unix, ssh

I'm having some fun trying to diagnose why A magento site is throughout the day hitting 99% CPU and bringing the site to a crawl.

Using the top command & strace I get pages and pages within seconds of stuff that looks like this:

```
close(19)                               = 0
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php", 0x7fffdc41c250) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/community/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php", 0x7fffdc41c250) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=5198, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php", O_RDONLY) = 19
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=5198, ...}) = 0
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=5198, ...}) = 0
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=5198, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 5198, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 19, 0) = 0x7fe4d81ed000
munmap(0x7fe4d81ed000, 5198)            = 0
close(19)                               = 0
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php", 0x7fffdc41b940) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/community/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php", 0x7fffdc41b940) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=34910, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php", O_RDONLY) = 19
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=34910, ...}) = 0
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=34910, ...}) = 0
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=34910, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 34910, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 19, 0) = 0x7fe4d8158000
munmap(0x7fe4d8158000, 34910)           = 0
close(19)                               = 0
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php", 0x7fffdc41cd20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/community/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php", 0x7fffdc41cd20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=3484, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php", O_RDONLY) = 19
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=3484, ...}) = 0
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=3484, ...}) = 0
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=3484, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3484, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 19, 0) = 0x7fe4d81ee000
munmap(0x7fe4d81ee000, 3484)            = 0
close(19)                               = 0
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/local/Zend/Controller/Response/Http.php", 0x7fffdc41c410) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/community/Zend/Controller/Response/Http.php", 0x7fffdc41c410) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Zend/Controller/Response/Http.php", 0x7fffdc41c410) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Http.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1106, ...}) = 0
lstat("/var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Http.php", O_RDONLY) = 19
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1106, ...}) = 0
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1106, ...}) = 0
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1106, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1106, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 19, 0) = 0x7fe4d81ee000
munmap(0x7fe4d81ee000, 1106)            = 0
close(19)
```

In the example above it's referencing some magento files, however quite often it's images. Be it product images, random images on page 40 of the blog etc etc. I'm by no means qualified to know what apache is doing, but I'd really like to sort it out!

We're running Magento with apache, mysql (on another server) and redis.

Any thought or potential avenues to explore?

Comment: You could try enabling [server-status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html#troubleshoot)
to see what is busy. You can see a live example output at [apache.org](https://www.apache.org/server-status).

Comment: Will check that out. Thanks!!

Comment: have you width or height attributes in you web pages `<img>` tags? perhaps apache is resizing images before sending to save space?  normally that's being done at the client side, but who knows... Sorry but I don't know about magento, :/